# How to use jQuery effects functions? jjQuery

Tags: jquery, html

In the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/slideDown/), effects such as `fadeIn()` and `slideDown()` act on initially hidden elements. But how do I get the elements to be initially hidden? When I view my HTML, the object I want to fade in is already visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible approaches:

1. In the `onDocumentReady()` function, call `.hide()` on those elements before calling the effects.
2. Set `visibility:hidden` in the styling of those elements.

Answer (score 1):

The `fadeIn()` jQuery method, for example, works with the css `opacity` property. Set your element style `opacity = 0` in either css or html style tag and it should work.
Then again, the `slideIn()` method works with visibility, so initially set its css property `visibility` to `hidden` or `collapse`.